# Nexus 7 gets stuck in loop and does not boot

Tags: nexus-7, 5.0-lollipop, android-versions

Recently tried to update to Android Lollipop. It downloaded the update but upon restart never installed Lollipop. Kept it for a few weeks and restarted it, could not load after that and the tablet keeps getting stuck in a loop from powering up it shows the bubbles then restarts, sometimes gets stuck on the bubbles screen for hours until the battery drains.
Tried restarting the bootloader and doing a factory wipe but still nothing, just made things worse (lost all my data for nothing). What can I do to make it boot properly?

Comment: Did you wipe cache and dalvik-cach?

Comment: yes i did wipe the cache,not sure about the dalvik cache bt there was an option that said 'wipe  the cache' @HasH_BrowN